# How to safe fire event, no matter what signature?

Tags: c#, delegates

Given I have delegates with different signatures:

```
public event Action Del1;
public event Action<int> Del2;
```

and I'd like to have ONE helper method to safely invoke the delegate. Calls like this would be ok:

```
FireEvent( Del1 );
FireEvent( Del2( 42 ) );
```

The following method works for the first delegate, but of course not for the second:

```
protected void FireEvent( Action action )
{
    if( action != null )
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

Is there some base class of Action I could use?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually you safely call the Action as :
`action?.Invoke()`
or `action?.Invoke(parm)`

Meaning u require signature anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using C# 6 then you can use the null-conditional operator to perform that check without the need for the "safe" method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn802602.aspx

> Leveraging the null-conditional operator, the entire set implementation is reduced to simply:
>
> `OnTemperatureChanged?.Invoke(this, value)`

I've created a .net fiddle to demonstrate this in action:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/hukL3u

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Action actionOne = () => { Console.WriteLine("One"); };
        Action<int> actionTwo = (int foo) => { Console.WriteLine("Two " + foo); };
        
        actionOne?.Invoke();
        actionTwo?.Invoke(12);
        
        actionOne = null;
        
        Console.WriteLine("One is null");
        
        actionOne?.Invoke();
        actionTwo?.Invoke(12);
        
        actionTwo = null;
        
        Console.WriteLine("Two is null");
        
        actionOne?.Invoke();
        actionTwo?.Invoke(12);
        
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
```

Which produces the output:

> One
>
> Two 12
>
> One is null
>
> Two 12
>
> Two is null
>
> Done

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Yep, thats quite nice, we still work with .NET 4.5 but that seems a good future solution.

Comment: The C# version is separate from the .net version. You should be able to use C# 6 features in VS 2015, and VS 2017.https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6 "This document describes the new language features in C# 6, the next version of C#. All of these are implemented and available in VS 2015."